# jQuery(this) and qtip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, qtip

Using jQuery's qtip plugin, I'm trying to display hidden value (that's already rendered wher hovering over the icons. The problem is that it's only grabbing the first item in the list and displaying that in qtip. Now I know the usual answer would be to use the "this" selector to target it, but in this case it's just not working...

Here's the code:

```
jQuery('li dl dd.job_icons').qtip({
    content: {
      prerender : true,
      text: jQuery('li dl dd.job_icons').html()
    }
});
```

And I've tried using this as well with no luck:

```
text: jQuery(this).html()
```

To get a clearer picture, check out [this link](http://rockstar.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/) and hover over the icons (some have different dates, and other will have salary and company name icons that should also be displayed)

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:** Here's the html that gets rendered

```
<li class="job job-alt job-featured"> 
 <dl> 
  <dt>Type</dt> 
  <dd class="type"><span class="jtype full-time">Full-Time</span></dd> 

  <dt>Job</dt> 
  <dd class="title"> 
    <strong>
    <a href="http://rockstar.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/jobs/front-end-developer-2/">Front End Developer</a>
    </strong> 
  </dd> 

  <dt>Location</dt> 
  <dd class="location">Anywhere</dd> 

  <dt>Job Admin</dt>    
    <dd class="job_icons"> 
    <div class="job_icons_wrap"> 
     <span class="job_date_detail">7 Feb</span> 
     <a href="#" class="job_date_icon"></a> 

     <a href="http://tinygiantstudios.co.uk" rel="nofollow" class="job_lister_detail">Tiny Giant Studios</a> 
     <a href="#" class="job_lister_icon"></a> 

     <span class="job_salary_detail jtype 100000-and-above">100,000 and above</span>
     <a href="#" class="job_salary_icon"></a> 
 </div>    
 </dd> 
</dl> 
</li>
```

Comment: We probably need to see the relevant html to know what's wrong with your selectors.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try each().  It has the proper scoping to use `this`.

```
jQuery('li dl dd.job_icons').each(function() 
    jQuery(this).qtip({
        content: {
          prerender : true,
          text: jQuery(this).html()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to have done the trick! Man, where were you 4 hours ago?!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have already solved this using Dennis' answer, here is what I came up with, using `each()`, which may or may not help you get what you want:

```
jQuery('li dl dd.job_icons a[class$=_icon]').each(function() {
    var classToSearch = jQuery(this).attr('class').replace('_icon', '_detail');
    jQuery(this).qtip({
        content: {
            prerender: true,
            text: jQuery(this).closest('dd.job_icons').find('.' + classToSearch).html()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of `.attr("class").replace(...` i would use `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()`

Comment: @James Khoury, I think you misunderstood the intent of that line of code. It is meant to just use the class of the matched `<a>` element, and replace the "_icon" part of the class string with "_detail", since for every "job_date_icon" / "job_salary_icon" / etc, there is a corresponding element with class "job_date_detail", "job_salary_detail", etc.

Comment: Then it uses that class to find the right element for that icon within the containing `dd` element.

Comment: Right. I did miss that there. It does seem awefully complex to just get the item before it `.prev()`? or even the `.closest().find()` could be replaced with `.siblings()`? Forgive me I'm just trying to simplify it as it looks like a good answer otherwise ... just complex.

Comment: Yeah, it did occur to me after I posted that perhaps `.siblings()` was a better choice. Either way, both should be fast, given the number of elements involved. Though my suggestion may be more robust to future changes, if a decision is made, for example, to wrap the tooltip elements in a containing element, or something that would otherwise break `.siblings()`.

Comment: Right but ... if that decision was made it could also be made that the element be moved outside the `dd` element altogether. Either situation should review the related code anyway. IMHO its better to be simple unless needed otherwise. why code a small change for something that might never be used.